# return a Count of emails inside Trash folder

Tags: outlook, office-js, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

How i can get the count of emails inside Trash folder with outlook web add-ins
i try to use EWS xml, but it show an error

```
let xml =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n' +
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\n' +
    '  <soap:Header>\n' +
    '    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />\n' +
    '  </soap:Header>\n' +
    '  <soap:Body>\n' +
    '    <m:GetFolder>\n' +
    '      <m:FolderShape>\n' +
    '        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>\n' +
    '      </m:FolderShape>\n' +
    '      <m:FolderIds>\n' +
    '        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox" />\n' +
    '      </m:FolderIds>\n' +
    '    </m:GetFolder>\n' +
    '  </soap:Body>\n' +
    '</soap:Envelope>';


var mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(xml, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  //var response = $.parseXML(result.value);
  //var extendedProps = response.getElementsByTagName("ExtendedProperty")
});
```

result :

```
message: "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
```

Comment: You could try to download Outlook ScriptLab from the store: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa200001603?tab=overview and use the "Send a message using EWS" sample to see if your xml is formatted correctly. There is also a sample EWS GetFolder request documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getfolder-operation#code

Comment: Also, I think you will need to use the "deleteditems" DistinguishedFolderId in your EWS request.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT when change it to "deleteditems" now get an error "The request is invalid"

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT   here is my code https://gist.github.com/mokhakh/f22900b890f27c2112aa5655b5506646

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request `PR_CONTENT_COUNT` MAPI property:

```
<FolderShape>
  <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
  <t:AdditionalProperties>
    <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyType="Integer" PropertyTag="0x3602"/>
  </t:AdditionalProperties>
</FolderShape>
```

Or you can request `TotalCount` property:

```
<t:AdditionalProperties>
  <t:FieldURI FieldURI="folder:TotalCount"/>
</t:AdditionalProperties>
```

**Update**: I could not execute your request above (same error), but the following works just fine from "EWS Request Pad" in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetFolder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <FolderShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyType="Integer" PropertyTag="0x3602"/>
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </FolderShape>
      <FolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="deleteditems"/>
      </FolderIds>
    </GetFolder>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```